# Max date and difference in days in Table in SAS Enterprise Guide?

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql, enterprise-guide, 4gl

I have table in SAS Enterprise Guide like below:

Data type:

- ID - numeric
- DT - date
- OF_1 - character
- OF_2 - character

Values are not sorted in original table, but it could be if it is important for solution

| ID | DT | OF_1 | OF_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 01MAY2021 | PR | PR |
| 111 | 05MAY2021 | PR | P |
| 111 | 10MAY2021 | P | P |
| 222 | 30MAY2021 | PR | M |
| 222 | 01SEP2022 | M | PR |
| 333 | 05SEP2021 | PR | P |
| 333 | 07SEP2021 | P | PR |
| 333 | 11SEP2021 | PR | M |
| 444 | 15AUG2022 | M | M |

And I need to create numeric column "RESULT" where:

- if he changed PR to P or M and did not return to PR -> `30SEP2022'd - "DT" of change PR to P or M`
- if he changed PR to P or M and return to PR -> calculate difference between: `("DT" of return to PR)` - `("DT" of change PR to P or M)`
- if he changed PR to P or M a few time -> calculate max days how he stay at P or M till return to PR or till 30SEP2022

So as a result I need something like below (**in DT column is date of the longest changed**):

| ID | DT | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 05MAY2021 | 513-> changed PR to P or M in 05MAY2021 and did not return to PR so `'30SEP2022'd -'05MAY2021'd = 513` |
| 222 | 30MAY2021 | 459 -> changed PR to P or M in 30MAY2021 and reutrn to PR in 01SEP2021 so '01SEP2021'd - '30MAY2021'd = 459 |
| 333 | 11SEP2021 | 384 -> changed PR to P or M 2 times: 05SEP2021 and 11SEP2021, but for the first time he lasted only 2 days because he returned to PR after 2 days, for the second time he lasted: `'30SEP2022'd - '11SEP2021'd = 384`, and for this ID max is 384 |
| 444 | - | 0 -> because he have never changed PR to P or M |

How can I do that in SAS Enterprise Guide normal SAS code or in PROC SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

```
proc sort data=have ; by ID DT ; run ;

data want ;
  set have ;
  by ID DT ;

  retain DAT_PR2PM MAX_PM_DAYS MAX_PM_DATE . ;
  if first.ID then call missing(DAT_PR2PM, MAX_PM_DAYS, MAX_PM_DATE) ;

  /* store date of PR > P/M */
  if OF_1 = 'PR' and OF_2 in('P','M') then DAT_PR2PM = DT ;

  /* P/M > PR, calculate days / retain max */
  if OF_2 = 'PR' and OF_1 in('P','M') and not missing(DAT_PR2PM) then do ;
    DAYS = sum(DT, -DAT_PR2PM) ;
    MAX_PM_DAYS = max(DAYS, MAX_PM_DAYS) ;
    if DAYS = MAX_PM_DAYS then MAX_PM_DATE = DT ;
    call missing(DAT_PR2PM) ; /* set back to missing */
  end ;

  /* last record for ID, seen PR > P/M but no P/M > PR */
  if last.ID and not missing(DAT_PR2PM) then do ;
    DAYS = sum(date(), -DAT_PR2PM) ;
    MAX_PM_DAYS = max(DAYS, MAX_PM_DAYS) ;
    if DAYS = MAX_PM_DAYS then MAX_PM_DATE = DT ;
  end ;

  /* output result for ID */
  if last.ID ; 

  keep ID MAX_PM_DAYS MAX_PM_DATE ;
run ;
```

Comment: Chris J, your solution looks almost good, but in your output there is no column "DT" where should be date of start of the longest change (as I described in my quqstion) - could you add that column, please ?

Comment: Chris J, could you modify your solution and add column "DT" with the date os start of the largest change per ID, please ?

Comment: Edited, two lines added.

Comment: Chris J, but your output after edition generate 2 columns: ID and MAX_PM_DAYS. In output shoud be three columns: ID, DT, MAX_PM_DAYS, could you change that please and add column "DT" to the output generated where will be date of start of the longest change ?

Comment: MAX_PM_DATE just needed adding to keep statement.

Comment: Chris J, it is not correct, are you sure your modification, because for example in output for ID = 111 DT column in output should be 05MAY2021 because this is the date of start of the longes change with duration 513 days, could you modify your answer ?